# Como eu insiro um menu?

Tags: c, menu

To com um projeto, e a parte final dele é a inserção do menu de escolha para usuário.

Eu deixarei o código original, pois de varias tentativas, todas foram sem sucesso.
Mesmo já inclui os case, switch.

Como seria a inserção do menu dentro do código, pois ja existe o comando do `printf`, só precisaria substituir.

Como eu insiro essa parte aqui:

```
printf("\n 1 - Inserir Mensagem ");
printf("\n 2 - Ver mensagem Criptografada ");
printf("\n 3 - Ver Mensagem Descriptografada ");
printf("\n 4 - Fechar Programa ");
printf("\n\nEscolha-----------\n--------uma-------\n------------opcao: ");
scanf("%d",&escolha);
```

Nesse codigo aqui:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define tam 250


typedef struct{
    char mensagem[tam];


}urna;

void criptografa(urna *criptografia);
void descriptografar(urna *cripto);

void criptografa(urna *cripto) {
    printf("Insira sua mensagem: ");
    gets(cripto->mensagem);



    int m;
    for(m = 0; m < strlen(cripto->mensagem); m++)
    {
        if(cripto->mensagem[m] >= 65 && cripto->mensagem[m] <= 90)
        {
            cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] + 3;

            if (cripto->mensagem[m] > 90)
                cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] - 26;
        }

        else if(cripto->mensagem[m] >= 97 && cripto->mensagem[m] <= 122)
        {
            cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] + 3;

            if (cripto->mensagem[m] > 122)
                cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] - 26;
        }

        else if(cripto->mensagem[m] >= 48 && cripto->mensagem[m] <= 57)
        {
            cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] - 5;

            if (cripto->mensagem[m] < 48)
                cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] + 10;
        }
    }

    printf("\nMensagem criptografada: ");
    printf("%s ", cripto->mensagem);
    printf("\n");
}

void descriptografar(urna *cripto) {

    int m;
    for(m = 0; m < strlen(cripto->mensagem); m++)
    {
        if(cripto->mensagem[m] >= 65 && cripto->mensagem[m] <= 90)
        {
            cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] - 3;

            if (cripto->mensagem[m] < 65)
                cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] + 26;
        }

        else if(cripto->mensagem[m] >= 97 && cripto->mensagem[m] <= 122)
        {
            cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] - 3;

            if (cripto->mensagem[m] < 97)
                cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] + 26;
        }

        else if(cripto->mensagem[m] >= 48 && cripto->mensagem[m] <= 57)
        {
            cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] + 5;

            if (cripto->mensagem[m] > 57)
                cripto->mensagem[m] = cripto->mensagem[m] - 10;
        }
    }

    printf("\nMensagem original: ");
    printf("%s ", cripto->mensagem);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    urna mensagem;
    criptografa(&mensagem);
    descriptografar(&mensagem);
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você possui o seguinte menu:

```
printf("\n 1 - Inserir Mensagem ");
printf("\n 2 - Ver mensagem Criptografada ");
printf("\n 3 - Ver Mensagem Descriptografada ");
printf("\n 4 - Fechar Programa ");
printf("\n\nEscolha-----------\n--------uma-------\n------------opcao: ");
scanf("%d",&escolha);
```

Você pode reduzir isto para:

```
int escolha = 0;

printf("\n 1 - Inserir Mensagem \n 2 - Ver mensagem Criptografada \n 3 - Ver Mensagem Descriptografada \n 4 - Fechar Programa");
printf("\n\nEscolha uma opcao: ");
scanf("%d",&escolha);
```

Agora para reutilizar o menu, podemos criar um método e inserir o menu dentro dele:

```
void menuEscolha() {
    int escolha = 0;

    printf("\n 1 - Inserir Mensagem \n 2 - Ver mensagem Criptografada \n 3 - Ver Mensagem Descriptografada \n 4 - Fechar Programa");
    printf("\n\nEscolha uma opcao: ");
    scanf("%d",&escolha);
}
```

Logo esta função pode ser inicializada no local em que quiser, como por exemplo:

```
int main() {
    menuEscolha();
}
```

**OBS:** Lembre-se que a função `void menuEscolha();` deve ser inserida antes do local o qual você irá utilizar, utilizando o exemplo acima:

```
void menuEscolha() {}

int main() {
    menuEscolha();
}
```

**NOTA:**

> Logo o valor do atributo `escolha` deve ser utilizado, como você não detalhou a sua pergunta, explicando **"o que?"** e **"como?"** deveria ser feito realmente com este menu, finalizo a minha resposta por aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Saudações

Provavelmente o que está faltando no seu código fonte é a inicialização correta da variável mensagem.

Em C, quando você quer criar uma variável de um tipo estrutura é necessário solicitar a alocação dinâmica daquele tipo de dado. Ficará algo mais ou menos assim.

```
    urna* mensagem = (urna*) malloc(sizeof(urna));
```

onde urna* significa que você quer criar um ponteiro para o tipo urna, mensagem é o nome da variável (urna*) é um cast para o C saber que o tipo de dados alocado é ponteiro para urna, e o malloc que alocará a quantidade de bytes em memória referente ao tipo de dado passado como parâmetro.

Sem fazer o malloc provavelmente você esteja recebendo um segmentation fault!

A outro detalhes, como o ponteiro está sendo alocado dinamicamente na hora de chamar as funções criptografa e descriptografar não será necessário colocar o & antes do nome da variável, ficará algo mais ou menos assim:

```
      criptografa(mensagem);
```

Boa sorte com seu exercício, qualquer dúvida posta ai!

Comment: Nota que em C (não C++) não precisas fazer o cast, na verdade é até recomendado que não o faças.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Um menu pode ser facilmente implementado utilizando as estruturas do-while e switch.

Para melhorar a legibilidade, recomendo a criação de uma função específica para ler a mensagem e inserir na urna, como por exemplo:

```
void lerMensagem(urna* cripto){
    printf("Insira sua mensagem: ");
    fgets(cripto->mensagem, sizeof(cripto->mensagem), stdin);
}
```

Exemplificando, no cenário proposto, o menu implementado ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
void menu(urna* cripto){
    int escolha = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n 1 - Inserir Mensagem ");
        printf("\n 2 - Ver mensagem Criptografada ");
        printf("\n 3 - Ver Mensagem Descriptografada ");
        printf("\n 4 - Fechar Programa ");
        printf("\n\nEscolha-----------\n--------uma-------\n------------opcao: ");

        scanf("%d",&escolha);

        switch(escolha){
            case 1: lerMensagem(urna* cripto); break;
            case 2: criptografa(urna* cripto); break;
            case 3: descriptografar(urna* cripto); break;
            case 4: exit(0); break;
            default: printf("\nOpção invalida, tente novamente.\n\n"); break;
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

já na main, somente seria necessário chamar a função menu passando a struct como parâmetro.

```
int main(){
    urna mensagem;

    menu(&mensagem);

    return 0;
}
```